# Shifting values to the left of a pandas dataframe without losing the leftmost values

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have the following dataframe in Pandas*:

```
   A  B  C  D
1  W1 W2 W3 W4
2     X1 X2 X3
3        Y1 Y2
4           Z1
```

I would like to transform this dataframe into the following shape:

```
   A  B  C  D
1  W1 W2 W3 W4
2  X1 X2 X3
3  Y1 Y2
4  Z1
```

Is there a way in Pandas to shape the dataframe like that? I have tried several aproaches:

First I tried by reversing the columns by using the [::-1] technique, but as you would imagine, it also reverse the order of the cells, which is not what I want.

Similarly, I tried shifting the columns to the left by using the [:-1] technique, but I lost the left column in doing so.

So my intuition is that there is some pivoting technique that I am not aware of.

*Note: *In case someone is curious, I have used **fillna("")** to clear out void cells, just to make a cleaner representation of the data.*

Comment: What's there in the blank spaces?

Comment: @Divakar As I specified in the question, here were NaNs which I cleared by using fillna("").

Comment: @JamesJ.-- before using `fillna` use the solution from above link and then replace NaNs. That should do.

Comment: I confirm that the solution proposed works. Sorry for the dup. question.